# Build class for estimation of cylinder (radius and height)

Tags: python, function, class

I am trying to write class called `Cylinder`. The constructor has two arguments, `r` the radius of a circle at the sides of the cylinder and `h` the height of a cylinder.  The method `calc_area` which so it computes the area of a cylinder and  method called `calc_volume` computes the volume of a cylinder.

With implementation  method `__str__` for this class so that when you call the builtin `print` function with a `Cylinder` object it prints "Cylinder with `radius={radius}` and `height={height}`." After that I implement the destructor method `__del__` for this class so that upon deletion of the object a message is printed "Deleting Cylinder with `radius={radius}` and `height={height}`."

After that, I tried to implement a getter and a setter method for the height attribute using the built-in `property` function. The setter method checks whether the height being set is positive. If it's negative print a message "Cylinders can't have a negative height".

Create an object of class `Cylinder` and then call the `get_area` and `get_volume` method, pass the object to 'print' to test `__str__`, and try getting and setting the height using the `object.height` notation. Finally, call `del` on the object to test the destructor method.

In order to this, I wrote this code below but obviously, I made some mistakes:

```
class Cylindar:
    def __int__(self,r,h):
        self.__r=r
        self.__h=h


    def calc_area(self):
     return self.r*2*3.14*h+2*3.14*r**r


    def calc_volume(self):
     return self.h*3.14*r**r*h


    def __str__(self):
        return "Cylinder with raduis="+str(self.r)

    def __del__(self):
        print("Deliting Cylinder with radius=",self.r,".")

    @property
    def r(self):
        return self._r
    @r.setter
    def r(self, r):
        if r<=0:
            print("Cylinder can't have negative radius")
        else:
            self._r=r

c.calc_area()
c.calc_volume()


print(c)
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and make code in accordance of guidelines above?

​

Comment: With that reputation you should know that is not what SO is for. If you get a specific error while running this code, show it and explain what happens as compared to what should be happening. I'll give you a freebie: `self.__r` and `self.__h` in `__init__` should be `self._r` and `self._h`

Comment: Please, check [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from circle import Circle  # Using the Circle class in the circle module
 
class Cylinder(Circle):
    """The Cylinder class is a subclass of Circle"""
 
    def __init__(self, radius = 1.0, height = 1.0):
        """Initializer"""
        super().__init__(radius)  # Invoke superclass' initializer (Python 3)
            # OR
            # super(Cylinder, self).__init__(radius)   (Python 2)
            # Circle.__init__(self, radius)            Explicit superclass class
        self.height = height
 
    def __str__(self):
        """Self Description for print() and str()"""
        # If __str__ is missing in the subclass, print() will invoke the superclass version!
        return 'Cylinder(radius={},height={})'.format(self.radius, self.height)

    def __repr__(self):
        """Formal Description for repr()"""
        # If __repr__ is missing in the subclass, repr() will invoke the superclass version!
        return self.__str__()   # re-direct to __str__() (not recommended)
 
    def get_volume(self):
        """Return the volume of the cylinder"""
        return self.get_area() * self.height  # Inherited get_area()
 
# For testing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cy1 = Cylinder(1.1, 2.2)  # Output: Cylinder(radius=1.10,height=2.20)
    print(cy1)                # Invoke __str__()
    print(cy1.get_area())     # Use inherited superclass' method
    print(cy1.get_volume())   # Invoke its method
    print(cy1.radius)
    print(cy1.height)
    print(str(cy1))           # Invoke __str__()
    print(repr(cy1))          # Invoke __repr__()
```